# Python 2.7: TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to programming and Python so please kindly excuse if this is a silly mistake.

I am trying to run a script where I want to generate sample data based on lognormal distribution and then plot a histogram of that data.

I keep getting error

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.lognormal(10000)

[n,bins,patches] = plt.hist(a, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\UQ&M\GUI Demos\WIP\Tester.py", line 10, in <module>
[n,bins,patches] = plt.hist(a, bins=50, color = 'red',alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2341, in hist
ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7650, in hist
if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have read similar queries on here however I can't seem to find a solution.

Your expert suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for putting your valuable time looking into this.

Comment: `a == inf`, a simple scalar. `hist(x, ...)` needs a sequence as first argument. You probably wanted `a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.lognormal(size=10000)`

Comment: @dhke: you might want to post that as an answer

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Nah, typographical error, close vote ;)

Comment: Thank you @dhke it did fix the error. Appreciate your valuable assistance :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the [matplotlib API](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)
`a` should be an array or sequence and if I'm right in your code it is a single number not an array